I have a question about resolving the 'timeout error' in GitHub actions
I want to run the python code that puts the data received from the API into the maria db daily via a github action.
but during test i met below error
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/hostedtoolcache/Python/3.9.19/x64/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pymysql/connections.py", line 644, in connect
    sock = socket.create_connection(
  File "/opt/hostedtoolcache/Python/3.9.19/x64/lib/python3.9/socket.py", line 844, in create_connection
    raise err
  File "/opt/hostedtoolcache/Python/3.9.19/x64/lib/python3.9/socket.py", line 832, in create_connection
    sock.connect(sa)
socket.timeout: timed out

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/runner/work/python_test/python_test/test2.py", line 14, in <module>
    conn = pymysql.connect(host=host, user=user, *** db=database)
  File "/opt/hostedtoolcache/Python/3.9.19/x64/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pymysql/connections.py", line 358, in __init__
    self.connect()
  File "/opt/hostedtoolcache/Python/3.9.19/x64/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pymysql/connections.py", line 711, in connect
    raise exc
pymysql.err.OperationalError: (2003, "Can't connect to MySQL server on 'marai db ip' (timed out)")

I tried pinging that IP and got a timeout message.
If that's the case, is access not allowed for that IP, and if so, what's the difference since it loads fine when I run the python code locally?
Thanks in advance.

Is your db hosted by AWS? Getting this same error attempting to run tests on my env.
